# Region fixed effects in OLS

Tags: regression, stata, dummy-variable

What is the Stata code for adding region fixed-effects in ordinary least squares regression? My dependent variable is volume of sale of a product and independent one is dummy variable, 1 for red pamphlet, 0 for blue pamphlet distributed to a sample of people over five districts. I want to include region fixed effects in the model. I tried generating dummy variables for the five regions and adding the dummies in the model.
Is this approach correct? If not, which one is?

`reg pamph sale income plotsize region1 region2 region3 region4 region5`

Comment: This seems correct although Arthur's answer saves the step of creating 5 extra variables. Also be careful about the dummy variable trap - if all data points belong to one of the 5 regions, you will have perfect collinearity (e.g. if regions 1 to 4 are zero, region 5 must be one), so the regression will fail. So either remove one of the regions (it becomes the baseline) or run the OLS without a constant (option `noconstant`)

Comment: @Dudelstein, just stumbled across this comment YEARS after the fact. You are correct about the 'dummy variable trap' as a statistical phenomenon. However, your comment will be a bit confusing to folks who use Stata, as the regression in Stata will not 'fail'. See my edit to the answer for detail.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me! I did not realize Stata handles perfect collinearity automatically, that's good to know. I like your answer edit, personally I would prefer to set the base level explicitly for clarity and easier interpretation.

Comment: Stata will set the baseline and drop collinear regressors, see my note below for how to set which one if needed. `noconstant()` should be used with care (i.e. probably not what you want to do). (a note for googlers of the future)

Comment: I agree with @Dudelstein's follow up: setting the base level explicitly is recommended!

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to control for group fixed effects.
The simplest (IMO) in your situation is to use a factor variable.
For example:

```
webuse nlswork
reg ln_w grade age i.ind_code
```

In your case this would look like:

```
reg pamph sale income plotsize i.region
```

Assuming that `region` is a variable with a unique id for each region.

Other options are `areg` (see `help areg`) or `reghdfe` (see [here](http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/)):

```
areg ln_w grade age, absorb(ind_code)
reghdfe ln_w grade age, absorb(ind_code)
```

#### Note on the dummy variable trap in Stata.

Stata checks for collinear regressors and drops them. Interested readers (and commenters) can review the output of the `reg` examples above to see this in action. If you would like to control the base level you can substitute `ib[level code]` (where `level code` is the id of the group you would like to assign as the base level), and this will be the group dropped by Stata.

See "Base Levels" under [Prefix Commands in the Stata manual for more details](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u11.pdf#u11.1.10Prefixcommands).